# Android Imge Picasso Square Cache Size

Tags: android, image, picasso, image-loading

Im using Picasso square library to load images in my android application. This works fine when doing it like this:

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(Properties.IMAGE_URL + i).transform(transformation).centerCrop().fit().into(imgeButton);
```

My problem is that the loading of the image is too slow and I would like the cache to be bigger than it is right now. I see that when working with only one image the cache works properly; The first time the image will not be cached and right after that every time the same code is called, the image will be fetched from the cached and not the network.
As the number of images increase, it seems that the cache is too small and images are replaced.  Can the cache size be modified / enlarged?

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify your own LRUCache for Picasso to use.

```
 Picasso picasso = new Picasso.Builder(context).memoryCache(
            new LruCache(cacheSize)).build();
```

I think by default, Picasso uses 1/7th of the available heap for it's LRU. But you can calculate what size you want by using the devices memory class.

```
int memClass = ((ActivityManager) mApplicationContext
            .getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE))
            .getLargeMemoryClass();
int cacheSize = 1024 * 1024 * memClass / 4;
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. How would you go about caching the next picture to be displayed? Let's say you are showing pictures from a gallery, how can you always cache the next picture to be displayed to avoid loading time?

Comment: hay @DejanRistic  i'am using picasso to load images from disk as follow picasso.with(context).load(file).into(imageview); ...... how can i set memory cash this way? thanx in advance

Comment: @Error Picasso supports using resources as image sources, so i assume it would work the same way. You can enable debugging to see the source of your images, it will tell you where they are coming from. 

Call setIndicatorsEnabled(true) on the Picasso instance. And it will have a small colored ribbon indicating the source. I believe blue is disk, green is memory, and red is network.

Comment: thanx for your answer @DejanRistic yes in new class that extend Application. i used Picasso.Builder to set memory cache and used setSingletonInstance to create singleton . and declared this class in manifest android:name=".classname" . and that works